# Gulp watch not working - cannot find module connect

Tags: node.js, wordpress, google-app-engine, gulp, gulp-watch

Trying to run my project using gulp (havent used gulp before and have inherited an exisiting project).

I install the dependencies into the wordpress theme directory.

Running *gulp watch* throws this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'connect'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\dev\projects\romac-website\web\app\themes\romac\node_modules\browser-sync\lib\utils.js:307:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I have tried to update npm but not sure if it is fine or the problem (still).

I also tried to ins install this module with `npm -g install connect`

What should I try next?

Comment: More information would be helpful.  Can you paste your gulpfile?

Comment: `npm install connect --save-dev`, this can also be thrown by a missing dependency  in one of the already installed modules.

Comment: I would like to share my gulp file but its massive long. How could I best do that? Just checking do you want to see gulpfile.js or package.json?

Comment: @niklon I ran that install command, now run gulp watch and the error seems to have moved on to can not find module micromatch. Is there someway I can tell it to install everything it wants at once, rather than it telling me whats missing one module at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the `node-modules` folder then reinstall **npm install connect --save-dev** Then retry running `gulp`